# How to associate gvim with extensionless files on Windows?

Tags: invocation, gvim, microsoft-windows

I would like to set gvim as the default program for opening files which do not have an extension (e.g. no `.txt`, `.php`, `.js`, `.css`, `.html` etc...) suffix as part of the file name.

e.g.: `README` or `INSTALL`.

I would like to do this on any version of Windows (although I am currently running Windows 7).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the configuration of the Windows operating system.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/13947/334516 - apparently someone got the answer from the Vim Wikia. :D

Comment: This is a useful question as such, but I agree with @toro2k that this question belongs on SuperUser.com. It has almost nothing to do with Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have full Administrator privileges to set the default program to launch when files with no extension are clicked. From a DOS prompt:

Use the `assoc` command with the extension `.` (which is used to denote the case where no file extension is present) and specify "No Extension" as the file type to associate with such extension:

```
assoc .="No Extension"
```

Now use the ftype command to specify the command to run when a file with no extension is clicked (the following assumes the latest version of Vim is installed in its default location on the `C:` drive):

```
ftype "No Extension"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe" "%1"
```

Comment: I think you can also use regedit to add these to your own personal area, without admin rights. See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Windows_file_associations